# How to remove first joined row Talend DI

Tags: file, join, talend, delimited

How to delete first matching row in a file using a second one ?

I use Talend DI 7.2 and I need to delete some rows in one delimited file using a second one containing the rows to delete. My first file contains multiple rows matching the second one but for each row in my second file I need to delete only the first row matching in the first file.

For example :

```
File A :                      File B :

Code | Amount                 Code | Amount
   1 | 45                        1 | 45
   1 | 45                        3 | 70
   2 | 50                        3 | 70
   2 | 60
   3 | 70
   3 | 70
   3 | 70
   3 | 70
```

At the end, I need to obtain :

```
File A :

Code | Amount
   1 | 45
   2 | 50
   2 | 60
   3 | 70
   3 | 70
```

Only the first match in file A for each row in file B is missing.

I tried with tMap and tFilterRow but it matches all rows not only the first one.

**Example edited : I can have many times the same couple code-amount in file B and I need to remove this same number of rows from file A**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using Variables within the Tmap. I created 3:

- v_match - return "match" if code and amount are in lookup file b.
- v_count - add to the count if it's a repeating value. otherwise reset to 0
- v_last_row - set the value of v_match to this before comparing again. this way we can compare current row to last row and get counts

Then add an Expression filter to remove any first match.

[image: tmap]

This will give the desired results:

[image: workflow results]

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to remove two same rows in file A ? For example if I add an other row "3 | 70" in file B, I have two same rows to remove in file A but this solution only works if I have a different code for each row I want to remove

Comment: for that I would use a tAggregateRow on lookup file and then loop file A through a java component flagging rows to remove. Then filter on the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete rows from a file, so you'll have to generate a new file containing only the rows you want.
Here's a simple solution. 
[image]

First, join your files using a left join between A as a main flow, and B as a lookup.
In the tMap, using an output filter, you only write to the output file the rows from A that don't match anything in B (`row2.code == null`) or those which have a match, but not a first match.
The trick is to use a `Numeric.sequence`, with the code as an id of the sequence; if the sequence returns a value other than 1, you know you've already had that line previously. If it's the first occurence of the code, the sequence would start at 1 and return 1, so the row is filtered out.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to remove two same rows in file A ? For example if I add an other row "3 | 70" in file B, I have two same rows to remove in file A but this solution only works if I have a different code for each row I want to remove